# Calculate delta(difference of current and previous row) mysql group by specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, datediff, difference

I have a table like : session is the name of the table for example
With columns: Id, sessionDate, user_id

What i need:
Delta should be a new calculated column

```
Id | sessionDate          | user_id | Delta in days
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2011-02-20 00:00:00 |     2    | NULL
2  | 2011-03-21 00:00:00 |     2    | NULL
3  | 2011-04-22 00:00:00 |     2    | NULL
4  | 2011-02-20 00:00:00 |     4    | NULL
5  | 2011-03-21 00:00:00 |     4    | NULL
6  | 2011-04-22 00:00:00 |     4    | NULL
```

Delta is the Difference between the timestamps
What i want is a result for Delta Timestamp (in Days) for the the previous row and the current row grouped by the user_id.

this should be the result:

```
Id | sessionDate         | user_id | Delta in Days
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2011-02-20 00:00:00 |     2   | NULL
2  | 2011-02-21 00:00:00 |     2   | 1
3  | 2011-02-22 00:00:00 |     2   | 1
4  | 2011-02-20 00:00:00 |     4   | NULL
5  | 2011-02-23 00:00:00 |     4   | 3
6  | 2011-02-25 00:00:00 |     4   | 2
```

I already have a solution for a specific user_id:

```
SELECT user_id, sessionDate, 
abs(DATEDIFF((SELECT MAX(sessionDate) FROM session WHERE sessionDate <  t.sessionDate and user_id = 1), sessionDate)) as Delta_in_days  
FROM session AS t
WHERE t.user_id = 1 order by sessionDate asc
```

But for more user_ids i didn´t find any solution

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Check this fiddle might be it will helpful to u.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bf493/52.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
drop table a;
create table a( id integer not null primary key, d datetime, user_id integer );
insert into a values (1,now() + interval 0 day, 1 );
insert into a values (2,now() + interval 1 day, 1 );
insert into a values (3,now() + interval 2 day, 1 );
insert into a values (4,now() + interval 0 day, 2 );
insert into a values (5,now() + interval 1 day, 2 );
insert into a values (6,now() + interval 2 day, 2 );

select t1.user_id, t1.d, t2.d, datediff(t2.d,t1.d)
from a t1, a t2
where t1.user_id=t2.user_id
and t2.d = (select min(d) from a t3 where t1.user_id=t3.user_id and t3.d > t1.d)
```

Which means: join your table to itself on user_ids and adjacent datetime entries and compute the difference.

Comment: Note that this solution does not scale well.

Answer (score 1):

If `id` is really sequential (as in your sample data), the following should be quite efficient:

```
select t.id, t.sessionDate, t.user_id, datediff(t2.sessiondate, t.sessiondate)
from table t left outer join
     table tprev
     on t.user_id = tprev.user_id and
        t.id = tprev.id + 1;
```

There is also another efficient method using variables.  Something like this should work:

```
select t.id, t.sessionDate, t.user_id, datediff(prevsessiondate, sessiondate)
from (select t.*,
             if(@user_id = user_id, @prev, NULL) as prevsessiondate,
             @prev := sessiondate,
             @user_id := user_id
      from table t cross join
           (select @user_id := 0, @prev := 0) vars
      order by user_id, id
     ) t;
```

(There is a small issue with these queries where the variables in the `select` clause may not be evaluated in the order we expect them to.  This is possible to fix, but it complicates the query and this will usually work.)

Comment: "using variables -- what do you have in mind? Please give us a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have choosen an answer here is another way of achieving it

```
SELECT
t1.Id,
t1.sessionDate,
t1.user_id,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,t2.sessionDate,t1.sessionDate) as delta
from myTable t1
left join myTable t2
on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
AND t2.Id = (
  select max(Id) from myTable t3
  where t1.Id > t3.Id AND t1.user_id = t3.user_id

);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33b397/1)**